In FastAPI, how to properly handle asynchronous external APIs which may never callback?
I am using FastAPI to build an API service. My service needs to call an external API through the network, let's call it ex_api. The documentation of ex_api states that it accepts tasks submitted by users and executes them asynchronously. The specific calling process is as follows:

My service sends a request to the create task endpoint of ex_api, and the request parameters contain a callback_url
The create task endpoint of ex_api immediately returns a response after receiving the request, which contains the id of the created task
ex_api silently processes the task
After processing, ex_api sends a request to callback_url, and the payload is the processing result of my task
My service returns a response after receiving the request, and the process ends

The problem is that ex_api is not very stable. Sometimes, it will get stuck in the third step above. But I have no way of knowing this, and I am always waiting for ex_api to call back. I have an idea for a fix, which is to just wait for a limited time for the callback from ex_api, and if the time is up and the callback is still not received, my service will look for another way. But I don't know how to do this. Please note that I have no right to modify any content or working method of ex_api.
My questions are as follows:

Are there any good best practices or experiences that you can share with me?
Can my fix be implemented? If so, how to do it?

Here is the code example of my problem, let's say my service is trying to add 1 to an integer and then multiply it by 2, and the addition step must rely on an external API over the network:
from typing import Any

import fastapi
import httpx
from pydantic import BaseModel

THIS_SERVER_URL = "https://fake.this.server.public.url"
CALLBACK_API = "/callback/plus_one"
CALLBACK_URL = f"{THIS_SERVER_URL}{CALLBACK_API}"
API_PLUS_ONE = "https://fake.api.url/api/plus_one"

app = fastapi.FastAPI()


class MyQuery(BaseModel):
    x: int


class MyResponse(BaseModel):
    message: str
    result: int


@app.post("/api/plus_one_mul_two", response_model=MyResponse)
async def post_plus_one_mul_two(params: MyQuery):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as c:
        response = await c.post(
            API_PLUS_ONE,
            json={
                "callback_url": CALLBACK_URL,
                "number": params.x,
            },
        )
    response.raise_for_status()
    result: dict[str, Any] = response.json()
    return {"message": result["message"]}


class CbQuery(BaseModel):
    message: str
    number: int


class CbResponse(BaseModel):
    message: str


async def fake_upload_to_oss(number: int):
    pass

# FIXME: May never receive callback!
@app.post(CALLBACK_API, response_model=CbResponse)
async def callback_plus_one_mul_two(params: CbQuery):
    if params.message == "ok":
        await fake_upload_to_oss(params.number * 2)
    else:
        raise Exception("failed")
    return {"message": "ok"}


You'd usually store a task id (from ex-api) in a database locally, and then go through that database and look for tasks that never got the callback within the expected timeframe - and do whatever you want to do with them (i.e. retry, submit them to another service, highlight them to a user, etc.)

I would also suggest instatiating the httpx.AsyncClient once at startup and reuse it across the application - please have a look at  this answer from more details and examples.

@Chris (1/2) This is a good idea, however, this may bring concurrency problems. My example is a great simplification of production code. In fact, I will use gunicorn+uvicorn worker to deploy my application in multiple threads. I know that the httpx asynchronous client is thread-safe, but the documentation indicates that httpx disables http2 by default, and as far as I understand, http1.x is not capable of handling multiple requests simultaneously on the same TCP link.

@Chris (2/2) And even if my application uses http2, my users are likely to not support http2, considering that http2 is not yet popular. So I didn't choose this mode in the end, but let each request build a client separately, and let a batch of requests share the asynchronous client (combined with TaskGroup) when high concurrency is required locally.

@MatsLindh Does this mean that I have to actively start a worker (maybe process, thread, or coroutine) to scan the database regularly (for example, every 3 minutes)?

@IsuxizSlidder Yes, either with something like apscheduler for having it in-process (which can be hard to coordinate if you have many workers), or using something like cron to run a task every x minutes.
